# Remote installation of Stored Procs on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm just setting up the live environment for my new project. Unlike my dev and testing systems, the live environment consists of a web server (Win 2003) and a separate DB server (MYSQL).

My installation process for each release of the software is nicely scripted, giving me full rollback options etc.

However, I can't work out how to install my stored procedures within that process. I can't run a MYSQL command line because MYSQL isn't installed on the web server, it only accesses the DB via ODBC.

Is there a means by which I can run MYSQL commands on the web server, via ODBC from a command line? I really want to keep it all together so I can run "Install v123" and everything whizzes off and gets installed in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution but: I had a very similar problem a number of years ago, and I eventually just wrote a little stand alone program to run my scripts at the end of the install.

Another common option is to have them run as part of a configuration utility/page the user goes to after setup, but I'm assuming you want to keep this as a 1 step installation.